# Is it possible to configure Laravel project after deploying it?

Tags: javascript, html, laravel, forms, model

I have Laravel 8 project that i uploaded it to cpanel and configure it but i forgot to finish "Contact us form"

because i need to create model and add the route

so is it possible to do it from the cpanel? or i need to do it locally with the terminal?

i didn't try to do it from cpanel yet but would be possible to create files there rather than using the terminal?

or the best way to do it locally then upload it again?

i will follow this tutorial:

https://codingdriver.com/create-contact-us-form-in-laravel-with-email-sending-example.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### ***Best practice:***

**Step 1:** Do your changes locally, face errors and solve them.

**Step 2:** Test/Debug and look for improvements.

**Step 3:** Upload your project to github/bitbucket or any other similar version control platforms as private project so that others can't access them.

**Step 4:** Enable shell access from your cPanel.

**Step 5:** Create an empty repository in your cPanel and Get SSH url for deployment.

**Step 6:** Upload your updated project through ssh.

### ***Easier Approach***

**Step 1:** Do your changes locally, face errors and solve them.

**Step 2:** Test/Debug and look for improvements.

**Step 3:** Upload them directly in cPanel.

**Note:** Deployed project should not be modified directly through cPanel, because there could be unexpected errors and your running project may become `down` rather some special cases and knowing what you are doing!

Comment: Thank you for your complete answer, i guess i will do it locally then, as you mentioned i might face unexpected errors